# How do I change colors on-the-fly in mintty?

Tags: command-line, mintty

How do I change the colors in a Cygwin mintty session which is already open?  Is it possible?

Use case:

Under environment-imposed time constraints, multiple terminal windows have been opened without forethought.  In order to reduce the risk of typing the commands for system A into the terminal for system B, it would be nice if they were different colors.  Is there some escape sequence or whatnot that can change the color scheme for a running session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here: http://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#Changing_colours

Comment: this didnt work in mintty 1.0.1, but I upgraded to 1.0.2 and can now change on the fly :)

Answer (score 8):

You can set the colours in the ~/.minttyrc file.  Even better you can get a prebuilt theme from here: https://github.com/mavnn/mintty-colors-solarized

Here is what I have in my ~/.minttyrc file:

```
BoldAsFont=yes
Transparency=off
OpaqueWhenFocused=yes
Columns=115
Rows=34
Term=xterm-256color
BackspaceSendsBS=yes
Font=Consolas
FontHeight=11
BellFlash=yes
Locale=en_GB
Charset=UTF-8
BoldAsColour=yes

ForegroundColour=131, 148, 150
BackgroundColour= 0, 43, 54
CursorColour= 220, 50, 47
Black= 7, 54, 66
BoldBlack= 0, 43, 54
Red= 220, 50, 47
BoldRed= 203, 75, 22
Green= 86, 222, 99
BoldGreen= 11, 170, 34
Yellow= 250, 250, 0
BoldYellow= 250, 246, 172
Blue= 38, 139, 210
BoldBlue= 13, 148, 150
Magenta= 211, 54, 130
BoldMagenta= 108, 113, 196
Cyan= 115, 205, 204
BoldCyan= 180, 212, 212
White= 238, 232, 213
BoldWhite= 253, 246, 227
```

And here is the result:

[image: Mintty screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

As a weekend project, I just created [mintty-colors](https://github.com/joakimkarlsson/mintty-colors), that can be used to switch between color schemes on the fly.

It comes with a few predefined themes, and you can add additional themes by creating a config file in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mintty has a menu, and one of the choices is *Options*

[image: a color picker]

Comment: This only allows edits of 3 colors, not the full ANSI pallette.  Currently you need to use the xterm control sequences to edit the other colors, as ak2s link suggests.